# Notification custom sound not work when I read it from data folder

Tags: android, notifications

I saved user selected music to data folder of my app but when I want to set that file with notification sound, notification sound not playing.

This is my channel code :

```
private fun createNotificationChannel(reminder : Reminder) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        var notifMusic = reminder.Ringtone
        notifMusic = notifMusic.substring(0,notifMusic.length-4)
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_Name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH ).apply {
            name = "Reminder Channel"+reminder.id
            description = "For reminder"
            enableLights(true)
            lightColor =Color.RED
            enableVibration(true)
            vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 300, 200, 500)
            lockscreenVisibility = NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            if (reminder.Ringtone !== "def") {
                 val musicNamea = notifMusic;
                setSound(Uri.parse(musicNamea), Notification.AUDIO_ATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT)
                Uri.parse("$musicNamea.mp3"))
            } else { 
             setSound(Uri.parse("${ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE}://${context.packageName}/${R.raw.waterdrop_drop}"), Notification.AUDIO_ATTRIBUTES_DEFAULT)
            }
        }
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

And notification code :

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
        .setLargeIcon(getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_pill_capsul))SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Date(reminder.remChild.AlarmDateTime)))
        .setContentTitle(reminder.reminder.Name)
        .setContentText(reminder.reminder.Description)
        .setWhen(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(reminder.reminder.Description))
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add, "Snooze", snoozePendingIntent)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setSound(Uri.parse(notifMusic))
        .build()
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(idNott, notification)
```

And this is my uri of music ringtone :

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/package/files/Ringtone/ring.mp3
```

I really don't know why it doesn't work.
When I set it from my RAW folder its work but when set it from data folder thats not work.